# Optimise JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
Tabzilla.fillZGContacts = function(){
   if (!Tabzilla.panel.id) return;
   $.ajax({
       url: 'zgcontacts.json',
      success: function(d){   // "Type","Name","Link","Contact","Location","Icon"
        Tabzilla.zgContacts = d;
        var countries = [];
        d.rows.forEach(function(row){
          if (row[0] == 'Country') countries.push(
            {link:row[2], contact:row[3], country: row[4]}
          );     
        });

        //alphabetically
        countries.sort(sortByKey('country'));

        //adding link 
        countryTemplate = function (country){
          s = '<a title="'+country.country+'" class="chapters_link" href="'
          +country.link+'" target="_blank">'
      +'<div class="chapters c_'+country.country.toLowerCase()+'">'
        +'<span class="flag-margin">'+country.country+'</span></div></a>' 
        return s;
        }


        var byletter = {};

        //count countries starting from each letter
        countries.forEach(function(c){        
          var firstletter = c.country.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
          if (byletter[firstletter]) byletter[firstletter]++;
          else byletter[firstletter]=1;
        });
        console.log(byletter);
        //prepare containers
        var panel = $("#"+Tabzilla.panel.id);
        var $cols = []; 

        $cols.push(panel.find(".c_COL4"));
        $cols.push(panel.find(".c_COL3"));
        $cols.push(panel.find(".c_COL2"));
        $cols.push(panel.find(".c_COL1"));
        var columns = $cols.length;        
        var targetlen = countries.length/columns;

        var FirstLetter = countries[0].country.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        var cc = [];

        //fill containers. this loop is buggy. should be reviewed.
        countries.forEach(function(c){
          var newFirstLetter = c.country.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
          if (FirstLetter != newFirstLetter)
          {

             var l1 = cc.length;
             var l2 = l1 + byletter[newFirstLetter];
             //condition maybe shd be changed..

             if (Math.abs(l2-targetlen) >= Math.abs(l1-targetlen)){
               var $col;
               if ($cols.length>0) $col = $cols.pop();
               cc.forEach(function(c){
                 $col.append(countryTemplate(c));
               });
               cc=[];

               //does not work :(
               //could generate another template with first letter raised
               $col.find('span').first().addClass("first-letter");
             }
             cc.push(c);
          }
          else cc.push(c);
          FirstLetter = newFirstLetter;
        });

      },
   });
}
```

The zgcontacts.json file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/4275805).

Any pointers in optimizing this is much appreciated.  For example, this loop:

```
countries.forEach(function(c)
```

Comment: Does not belong here, because the code does not work. `var $col; if ($cols.length>0) $col = $cols.pop(); cc.forEach(function(c){ $col.append(countryTemplate(c)); });` This part cannot work, $col is undefined.

Comment: @ANeves yes it is. `$cols` is defined further up as `var $cols = [];` and `$col` is declared `var $col;` and then defined `$col = $cols.pop();`

Comment: @JamesKhoury thanks for correcting. But (1.) if `cols.length == 0`? $col is undefined, and one cannot do `$col.append`; unless this never happens, in which case the `if` is vestigial code and only serves to trick or confuse the reader. Also, (2.) what about that `//does not work :(` comment in the code?

Comment: @ANeves shall i move this to stackoverflow, but i am unsure if it is possible?

Comment: @khinester if the code does work, it should stay here. If it does not, it should be moved. (I think only admins can move it.) This is just my opinion, though, and JamesKhoury disagrees.

Comment: earlier i made a post on stackoverflow and was told it is better here ;(

Comment: @khinester You have to descide if this works or not. If it does then Code review can help you write it better. Otherwise take it to StackOverflow with the problem and someone will help you fix it. (Not improve it).

Comment: ... but please, if/when it comes back, make sure the formatting is more readable (indenting, braces, etc... ) See @JamesKhoury answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use braces `{` in all your if blocks. It makes it easier to read.

```
if (byletter[firstletter]){
    byletter[firstletter]++;
}else{
    byletter[firstletter]=1;
}
```

You have `for` loops like : `countries.forEach(function(c){` which are also hard to read. I'd only use this if you have a function you want to apply.

```
for(var countryindex = 0; countryindex < countries.length; countryindex++)
{
    var c = countries[countryindex];
    // ...
}
```

Use descriptive variable names.

```
if (FirstLetter != newFirstLetter)
{
    var l1 = cc.length;
    var l2 = l1 + byletter[newFirstLetter];
```

What is `l1` & `l2` ? What is `c` or `cc`?

Comment: @konijn javascript has `for` and `for .. in` I think they are much more readable and debuggable than `[].forEach(`. When would you favour it over the more traditional for loops?

Answer (score 5):

The location of your `countryTemplate` function breaks the flow of your code, you should put it at the very end. Also I would encourage you to use some templating routine, you could use this one:

```
function fillTemplate( s )
{ //Replace ~ in s with further provided arguments
  for( var i = 1 ; i < arguments.length ; i++ )
    s = s.replace( "~" , arguments[i] );
      return s;
}
```

Then your countryTemplate could be :

```
 countryTemplate = function (country)
 {
   var template = '<a title="~" class="chapters_link" href="~" target="_blank">' +
                    '<div class="chapters c_~">' +
                      '<span class="flag-margin">~</span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                  '</a>';
   return fillTemplate( template , country.country
                                 , country.link
                                 , country.country.toLowerCase()
                                 , country.country

 }
```

This could be DRY'er of course, since I repeat `country.country` a number of times, I leave the final code to you.

Furthermore, there is no reason not to merge the extraction of the countries and the calculation of `byletter`, it will save you a 'forEach` call:

```
    var countries = [],
        byletter  = {};

    d.rows.forEach(function(row){
      if (row[0] == 'Country'){
        var country = { link:row[2], contact:row[3], country: row[4] };
        var firstletter = row[4].toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        countries.push( country );
        byletter[firstletter] = ( byletter[firstletter] || 0 ) + 1;
      }
    });
```

Finally, your *buggy loop* is very badly written, I cannot tell what you are trying to achieve with that code. Maybe you should comment each section with what it is supposed to do and indeed follow the suggestions of James Khoury.